# Basic difference between setstate and other state management like provider in flutter

Tags: flutter

Basic difference between setstate and other state management like provider in flutter ,I am beginner to flutter, where to use provider instead of set state ,

if we set state what's is disadvantages of set state when more usage of the app

Comment: *"I am beginner to flutter"* - check [List of state management approaches](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) then (and/or [State management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) in general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single widget, setState is great.

If you need to share state between two widgets, in your constructor arguments you can pass state values and functions that manipulate the state of the parent widget.

As number of widgets increase and your tree gets deeper, you would find that going on this way is too verbose and intermediary widgets get a lot of boilerplate to hand over variables/functions to children. This is when you feel there should be a better way. That better way is state management.